# get last 08 days in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I created a measure to get last 08 days with the MAX date in the date table.This is the measure,

```
dynamic Date =
VAR _select =
CALCULATE ( 
    MAX ( DateTable[Date] ), 
    ALLSELECTED ( DateTable[Date] ) 
)

VAR _last7days = _select - 7
RETURN
    IF ( _select > _last7days, 1, 0 )
```

but this shows dates from 1st of january to 22nd of january. i need to get only last 08 days.

And i need to put a filter in the filter pane like this,

Dynamic date= 1

image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved my requirement using this measure,

```
Date_Range =
VAR selecteddate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( DateTable[Date] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( DateTable[Date] )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        AND (
            MAX ( DateTable[Date] ) > selecteddate - 8,
            MAX ( DateTable[Date] ) <= selecteddate
        ),
        1,
        0
    )
```

and put a this measure in the filter pane to get only "1".

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Nice to see you got your solution. You can at least give an up vote/accept solution for the answer that direct you to your solution. Voting is the real thanks here.

Answer (score 1):

Try something as below-

```
dynamic Date =
VAR max_date=
CALCULATE ( 
    MAX(DateTable[Date]), 
    ALLSELECTED(DateTable[Date]) 
)

RETURN IF (DATEDIFF(MIN(DateTable[Date]), max_date, DAY) > 7, 0, 1)
```

The output should be looks like below-

[image]

Comment: last part of the measure RETURN IF (DATEDIFF(DateTable[Date], max_date, DAY) > 7, 0, 1) is not supported. After DATEDIFF cant use DateTable[Date]

Comment: Hi @Mishi, I missed one thing and updated now accordingly. You can check now.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of that could break your code is the existence of some other filter when evaluating the _select variable.

You might try to remove all filters from `DateTabe` and the re-apply the filter over the date like follows

```
dynamic Date =
VAR _select =
CALCULATE ( 
    MAX ( DateTable[Date] ), 
    REMOVEFILTERS( DateTable ),
    ALLSELECTED ( DateTable[Date] ) 
)

VAR _last7days = _select - 7
RETURN
    IF ( _select > _last7days, 1, 0 )
```